# Why $\frac{d}{dt}f(x+t(y−x))<0$ if $x < y, f(y) < f(x)$

Tags: derivatives

Here excerpt from a book:

> Аssume that $f$ satisfies $\nabla f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$, but is not
> nondecreasing, i.e., there exist $x,y$ with $x < y$ and $f(y) < f(x)$.
> By differentiability of $f$ there exists at $t\in[0,1]$ with
>
> $$\frac{d}{dt}f\left(x+t(y−x)\right) =\nabla f\left(x+t\left(y−x\right)\right)^T(y−x)<0.$$

I don't understand why the derivative is less than zero? The function could look like on the image.
[image]

The book is *Convex Optimization* by Stephen Boyd and Lieven Vandenberghe, page 109.

Comment: It's not that it's always negative, it's that its negative somewhere.

Comment: It isn't saying **for all** but rather for **some.**

Comment: Suppose otherwise that $\frac{d}{dt}f(x+t(y-x))\geq 0$ for all $t\in[0,1]$. Can you find a contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(t)\equiv f(x+t(y-x))$ be defined on $[0,1]$. Then, $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$. So by the Mean Value Theorem, there is some $t^*\in(0,1)$ such that
$$
g'(t^*)=\frac{g(1)-g(0)}{1-0}=f(y)-f(x)<0.
$$
It remains to expand the leftmost expression above.